# What is restore.dg file and what is its syntax?

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I've upgraded from xproj to csproj and I keep getting

```
dotnet restore  restore.dg
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: restore.dg
```

and if I add the file to my project dir then it will say

```
C:\Git\XX\WebSite\restore.dg(1,1): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

C:\Git\XX\WebSite>dotnet restore restore.dg
C:\Git\XX\WebSite\restore.dg : error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Root element is missing.
```

1. So what is this file and what is it for?
2. What should be in it?
3. Where is documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like conversion goes wrong. There should no be any `restore.dg` files as result of `dotnet migrate`. Revert back to original `xproj` and try to re-run migration.

Of course you can simple try to delete this `restore.rg`, but as soon as migration looks to be unsuccessful - you may have incomplete/bad `csproj` file.

If migration fail again, you may try to run migration manually from command line (not from VS). Here is instructions for **single-project** solution:

1. Revert back to xproj structure. You should have `project.json`, `project.lock.json`, `yourporject.xproj` and optional `youproject.xproj.user`
2. Manually delete `global.json` from root of your solution folder and make sure it does not exist in upper/parent directories (it may "pin" you to old `dotnet` version).
3. Start command  line and navigate to your project folder (where `project.json` resides).
4. Ensure you have latest SDK - run `dotnet --info` - it should not show any `preview` versions, must be 1.0.0 or above ([1.0.3 is current](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md))
5. run `dotnet migrate`. It must run successfully (green text), all 4 files listed in #1 should disappear, one new file `youproject.csproj` should appear. Internally, it will contain all (or almost all) information from `project.json` - but double-check this, sometimes it loses some package properties like "Copyright", "Company" etc - you will need to put them back via project properties in VS later. For asp.net projects - `runtimeconfig.template.json` may appear too (with `"gcServer": true` instruction)
6. Now you should be able to open project in VS 2017. I recommend remove `.vs`, `bin` and `obj` folders before start to ensure VS will restore packages and rebuild project from ground.

For **multi-project** solution - all my migrations are failing with errors when converting test projects which references "main" project. I had no time to debug this, so to solve this I manually remove `project.lock.json` from test project(s), manually remove reference to original code project from their `project.json` and then run migration from solution root (once for all projects).

Comment: The vs2017 migrator told me all is ok. When I remove the file it tels it cannot find project. When and only when I create the file in website project's dir it will change the error to something else like what i've listed in original post. My converion was simply to open the project and let it convert. I dont expect this to be undeterminitive. Main clue-question: doest vs2017 install newest SDK for dotnetcore because I didn't install it seperately?

Comment: In VS 2017 whether the SDK is installed depends on the workloads that you selected. 
You can check whether/which version is installed by opening the Visual Studio Installer and then checking under "Invididual Components' for the respective Visual Studio Installation.

Comment: @doker I updated my answer with steps for manual project migration